# Apache not reachable from outside: Error 502

Tags: networking, server, apache2, error-handling, reverse-proxy

I've read various similar threads already but the solutions don't seem to apply to my setup.
I just installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 with a fresh LAMP stack on a local server.
Within the LAN (entering just the internal IP address) it works perfectly fine. The default site loads. I haven't changed any ports in the configuration, it's all on the default *80.

However, when I try to access the site from the Internet, I get a 502 error.
I'm using DuckDNS as I don't have a static IP address from my ISP.
Incoming traffic to various subdomains gets picked up by NGINX proxy manager running on a local machine here. It routes to the respective internal addresses. This works fine with all web services I'm running on this network. Just the apache server seems to be the exception.

I've kept the ufw to inactive to ensure it doesn't block any connection.

I haven't messed around with the configuration, it's all based on a fresh installation. Therefore, any hint would be highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The 502 is talking about a "bad gateway", which is usually related to routing. There should be an error log somewhere, either with nginx or Apache, that says *why* that 502 is taking place 

Comment: Does both apache and nginx run on port 80?

Comment: Yes, both were running on port 80. I tried changing the apache2 to 8080 and forwarding the nginx reverse proxy to 8080, too. Still the same issue.
Will have to look at the error logs - anything specific to watch out for?

Comment: Just found this in the nginx error log:

"connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: [ip address], server: subdomain.domain.net, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://192.168.178.137:8080/favicon.ico", host: "subdomain.domain.net", referrer: "https://subdomain.domain.net/"

not sure what to read out of this though ... searching the web now, but couldn't find any solution thus far. The apache server is the only affected service that gets this error.